# Google OAuth 2.0 + Ruby on Rails 404: "Not found. Authentication passthru."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth, google-oauth

Below is the relevant code (do let me know if I'm missing anything!).

routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks' }

devise_scope :user do 
    match '/sessions/user', to: 'devise/sessions#create', via: :post
    get '/join' => 'users/registrations#new'
end

resources :users do
    resources :video_lessons do
      resources :likes
    end
end

resources :users, only: [:show, :index]
```

devise.rb:

```
if Rails.env.production?
    config.omniauth :google_oauth2, ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID_PROD'[, ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET_PROD'], {}
else
    config.omniauth :google_oauth2, ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID_DEV'], ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET_DEV'], {}
end
```

omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

```
  def google_oauth2
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])

    if @user.persisted?
      flash[:notice] = I18n.t 'devise.omniauth_callbacks.success', kind: 'Google'
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
    else
      session['devise.google_data'] = request.env['omniauth.auth'].except(:extra) # Removing extra as it can overflow some session stores
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url, alert: @user.errors.full_messages.join("\n")
    end
  end
```

devise/registrations/new.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Sign up with Google", user_google_oauth2_omniauth_authorize_path %>
```

The authorized redirect URIs in my Developer's Console are:
http://localhost:3000/users/auth/google_oauth2 and
https://localhost:3000/users/auth/google_oauth2

I've followed the docs (https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2) exactly, to no avail.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I recently got this working through this [guide](https://johnofsydney.github.io/notes/rails/rails_social_login.html).
A more descriptive resource, and the source of the guide, is this [official wiki example](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview).

This [commit](https://github.com/ikraamg/Great-Books/commit/0bd31ec653f11e077e818b9e011d15292d3a9f2d) shows all the files I changed to get google and github set up on my rails login page using the guide I mentioned first.

Just make sure when you use either of the guides, that you remove extra part of the data as it can overflow some session stores. The guides **do not** include this important piece of information. So in this line of omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb, **your current code is correct**:

```
...
    else
          session['devise.google_data'] = request.env['omniauth.auth'].except(:extra) # Removing extra as it can overflow some session stores
....
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to "Sign in with Google", user_google_oauth2_omniauth_authorize_path, method: :post %>
```

The request should be 'post'